# How to get Integer from Cardano.Ledger.BaseTypes.TxIx

Tags: plutus, ledger

I am using the following function from the Plutus pioneer program:

```
stakeReferenceLedgerToPlutus :: Ledger.StakeReference StandardCrypto -> Maybe Plutus.StakingCredential
stakeReferenceLedgerToPlutus (StakeRefPtr (Ptr (SlotNo x) y z)) = Just $ StakingPtr (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral y) (fromIntegral z)
```

But the latest release of Plutus-apps seems to require a change, because **`fromIntegral y`** does not work anymore. See error below:

```
error:
    • No instance for (Integral Cardano.Ledger.BaseTypes.TxIx)
        arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
    • In the second argument of ‘StakingPtr’, namely ‘(fromIntegral y)’
```

The same is true for **`fromIntegral z`** but for `Cardano.Ledger.BaseTypes.CertIx`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on the LHS you have:

```
StakeRefPtr (Ptr (SlotNo x) y z)
```

but `StakeRefPtr` is defined (in `cardano-ledger` repo, file `libs/cardano-ledger-core/src/Cardano/Ledger/Credential.hs`) as:

```
   | StakeRefPtr !Ptr
```

and `Ptr` is defined as:

```
data Ptr = Ptr !SlotNo !TxIx !CertIx
```

and `TxIx` is defined as:

```
newtype TxIx = TxIx Word64
```

That means, to get your code closer to working you should try:

```
stakeReferenceLedgerToPlutus :: Ledger.StakeReference StandardCrypto -> Maybe Plutus.StakingCredential
stakeReferenceLedgerToPlutus (StakeRefPtr (Ptr (SlotNo x) (TxIx y) z)) = Just $ StakingPtr (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral y) (fromIntegral z)
```

You probably also need to do the same for the `z` which is defined as a:

```
newtype CertIx = CertIx Word64
```

Comment: Thanks! Pattern matching to get the wrapped type makes complete sense.